# Using string from a file in a function

Tags: c++, casting

I have this function in c++

```
double f_x(double y , string sfy )
{
  return sfy;
}
```

1. I want to read the string sfy from a file and pass it to the f_x function.
2. sfy contains something like y or cos(y) or exp(y).
3. when I pass y and sfy to the f_x, I want f_x calculates sfy and return it.

I can do number 1 and 3 but the problem is that the type of f_x is double and sfy is string, so I get error.

I can not change the type of f_x to anything else it should be double or float.

How can I overcome this problem namely what should I do in order to f_x returns sfy as double.

Comment: Do you mean that you would have a call like f_x(3.14, "cos(y)") and you would actually like it to return the cosine of y?

Comment: yes i do.
i will use this function to solve an integro-differential equation.
this function is a minimal example of my real function.
if fact sfy contains a very large expression in temrs of several variables.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

std::map<std::string, double(*)(double)> m;

double f_x(double y , std::string sfy )
{
    if (m.find(sfy) == m.end()) throw "Invalid operation.";
    return m[sfy](y);
}

int main()
{
    m["exp"] = std::exp;
    m["cos"] = std::cos;
    m["sin"] = std::sin;

    std::ifstream file("test.txt");
    std::string op;
    std::getline(file, op);

    std::cout << f_x(42.0, op);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
There are some problems with this code.
1-in real situation sfy(the string) contains a very large expression in terms of several variables, but i think your code is suitable when there is one variable and one expression.
2-Because there are several variables in sfy so it is necessary that i put cos or sin or exp in test.txt with their arguments.
here in below is a small expression of what i have in sfy

Comment: -1. E^(s-t+t1-t2) Cos[1.88346 t-1.88346 t2] Cos[1.88346 t1-1.88346 t2] Sin[1.88346 s-1.88346 t] Sin[1.88346 s-1.88346 t1]

Comment: as you see there are 4 variables s,t1,t2 and t

Comment: In that case you need a parser of some sort. Perhaps you should look for some existing tools that would do that (flex, lex, etc...).

Comment: OTOH, extracting arguments from file isn't that hard. Perhaps you should update the question with an example expression and explain how would you want to parse it.

Comment: I don't know anything about "parse". Is there a tutorial about it?

Comment: You could start at wikipedia entry for "parsing". [This book](http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Principles-Practice-Using-C/dp/0321543726) is a great resource for learning input handling. It teaches it by making a calculator.